# Style tags inside "selectInput" rShiny

Tags: html, r, styles, shiny

I have a reactive selectInput and I am hoping to make part of it bold. Here is the code:

ui.r:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
numericInput("num", "Number of Variables",value=2),
uiOutput("select3")
))
```

server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  df<-reactive({
    s<-rep(0,input$num)
    for(i in 1:input$num){
      s[i]<-paste("Name",i,sep="")

    }
    s
  })

  dflist<-reactive({
    s<-rep(0,input$num)
    for(i in 1:input$num){
      s[i]<-paste("label",i,sep="")

    }
    s
  })

  output$select3 <- renderUI({
    x1=dflist()
    x1<-paste((df())," ", " (", toupper(x1), ")", sep="")
    select.value3<-(x1)
    selectizeInput("UseVar", "Use # Variable (OPTIONAL):", choices=c("None",select.value3),
                   multiple=F,selected="None")

  })
})
```

I would like Name1 **(LABLE1)**, Name2 **(LABLE2)**, etc. to appear in the drop down selectInput. However, if I try

```
strong(toupper(x1))
```

in the paste() function my dropdown appears as Name1 < strong>(LABLE1)< /strong>'. Is there any way to accomplish this?